# Radio button allow multiple selections in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

Basically I am trying to add radio button dynamically in JavaScript. Here is the codes:

```
function addToFilterBox(content, layerInfo) {
    console.log("checked = " + layerInfo.checked);
    content.text += "<tr><td><input class=\"" + layerInfo.id + "\" type=\"radio\" onclick=\"toggleOverlayer('" + layerInfo.id + "')\" ";

    if (layerInfo.checked == "1") {
        content.text += "checked='checked'";
    } 
    content.text += ">" + layerInfo.label + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td><div id=\"" + layerInfo.id + "\"></div></td></tr>";
};
```

My current situation is the radio button allow multiple selection and once it is selected, it cannot be unselected. I wonder how to restrict to select one radio button each time. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
    function toggleOverlayer(id){
if ($("."+id).prop("checked")) {
    showOverlayer(id);
} else {
    hideOverlayer(id);
}
}

function showOverlayer (id){
    var dynamap = overlayObjects[id];

    if (dynamap == undefined || dynamap == null || !dynamap) {
        loadMapService(id, 0.8);
    }

    dynamap = overlayObjects[id];

    dynamap.setMap(map);

    createSlider(id);
    $("#"+id).show();

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(dynamap.getMapService(), 'load', function() {
        dynamap.getMapService().layers[duNameDic[id]].visible = true;
        dynamap.refresh();
    });
}

function hideOverlayer(id){

    var dynamap = overlayObjects[id];

    dynamap.setMap(null);

    $("#"+id).hide();   

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(dynamap.getMapService(), 'load', function() {
        dynamap.getMapService().layers[duNameDic[id]].visible = false;
        dynamap.refresh();
    });
}
```

Comment: You didn't give your button a name. Radio buttons are grouped by the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

single selection you need to use onclick even handler & in on click you should disable the button.

```
function addToFilterBox(content, layerInfo) {
console.log("checked = " + layerInfo.checked);
content.text += "<tr><td><input name=\"chkbx\" class=\"" + layerInfo.id + "\" type=\"radio\" onclick=\"clickHandle(this,\""+layerInfo.id+"\");\" ";

if (layerInfo.checked == "1") {
content.text += "checked='checked'";
} 
content.text += ">" + layerInfo.label + "</td></tr>" + 
    "<tr><td><div id=\"" + layerInfo.id + "\"></div></td></tr>";
};

function clickHandle(ele,layerid){
   $(ele).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$( "[name='chkbx']" ).each(function( index, element ){hideOverlayer($(this).attr('class'));});
    toggleOverlayer(layerid);
   //Put anycode here ele is clicked item
}
```

Comment: but it only works for the first radio button. When I try to toggle for other layers, it does not work

Comment: @Newbie. TO allow multiple selection you need to have a unique name for each button.try updated should

Comment: No no, what I trying to do is only allow one selection. But when I select another, the previous one will be deselected. Currently it works in this way: When I select the first and then second, the first one stays.

Comment: How should I do like when I select another one, the previous one which is deselected will perform some codes? Cause when I deselect I need to perform hideOverlay() as edited portion.

Comment: You can use onclick handler,And to check whether item is selected use $(this).attr('disabled');

Comment: Mind to provide me with some example as I am quite confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54162/discussion-between-newbie-and-madterry).

Comment: Can you check the chat? I have something to ask you.

Answer (score 0):

give your radio buttons a name attribute and have all the names be the same value.

```
function addToFilterBox(content, layerInfo) {
console.log("checked = " + layerInfo.checked);
content.text += "<tr><td><input class=\"" + layerInfo.id + "\" type=\"radio\" onclick=\"toggleOverlayer('" + layerInfo.id + "')\" name=\"group\" ";

if (layerInfo.checked == "1") {
content.text += "checked='checked'";
} 
content.text += ">" + layerInfo.label + "</td></tr>" + 
    "<tr><td><div id=\"" + layerInfo.id + "\"></div></td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by name attributes? Could you please show me some examples?

Comment: I added an example. your input element should have name="group" just like you have id, type. They should all be the same to group them together. then only one in the group can be selected at a time

Comment: it means you should give a common `name` for your `tag` so that you can iterate the radio buttons by using `document.getElementsByName('name')`

Comment: It works for now but is there any way to make it like when  select another one, the previous map layer will be wiped off? Cause currently the radio button just keep on stacking the map layers

Comment: You can have a function to remove the existing radio button before `addToFilterBox`

Comment: @jhyap Would you mind to provide me with some example?